# List area of Sentinel 2

Tags: google-earth-engine

I tried to define area of NDWI from 2017-2019 but only show list of date and Area (F can not change).

Can you fix my code for me?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f0955df742de0f0b533f7778fd6c9349

or

```
// Data 
var Sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2");

var Lake = ee.FeatureCollection("ft:1DZkHTe3rWHS7DDfBcxMQ-DUTtkrDgcYmw1TVO6Gt")
Map.centerObject(Lake,15);
Map.addLayer(Lake,{},"Ha Thuong")
// filter data and location
var collection = Sentinel2.filterDate
('2017-12-12', '2019-9-5').filterBounds(Lake);
print(collection); 
print(collection.toList(100).get(0));

var a = collection.toList(collection.size()).map(function(img){
img = ee.Image(img)
// Display true color image
//var Sentinel2_ = Map.addLayer(collection.min().clip(Lake), {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 2048}, 'Sentinel2_');

// calculate ndwi from sentinel
function s2ndwi(img){
  var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI');
  return img.addBands(ndwi);
}
// run ndwi on all images
collection = collection.map(s2ndwi);

// select maximum NDWI
s2ndwi = collection.select("NDWI").max();

// set the threshold

var THRESHOLD = 0.1;

// select pixels greater than threshold
s2ndwi = s2ndwi.gt(THRESHOLD);

// set visualization 
//var ndwi_viz = {bands:"NDWI", min:-0.3, max:0.3, palette:"000000, 0000ff"};
// add the map as a layer
//var ndwi_2017 = Map.addLayer(s2ndwi.updateMask(s2ndwi).clip(Lake), ndwi_viz, 'ndwi_2017' );


var area = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(10000)
var area_image = s2ndwi.multiply(area).select([0],['F ha']);


var areas = area_image.reduceRegion({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: Lake, //.geometry(),
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels:5e13,
  // return: collection
})

var idate = ee.Image(img).date();

return [idate, areas]
})
var l = a.map(function(b){
  var c = ee.Feature(b)
  return c
})
print (l)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, your code makes no sense. You are making 125 exactly similar images by constructing a maxNDWI of the complete collection during each iteration, resulting in the same images. Using your current code, something like this could help you extract a list of dates and areas:

First, map over the images (don't make a list of it):

```
var a = collection.map(function(img){
```

Using your provided code, then return the date and area as property:

```
var idate = ee.Image(img).date();
return img.addBands(s2ndwi).set('dateFormat', idate.format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
            .set('area', areas.values().get(0));
})
```

and then use `aggregate_array` to transform the data into lists:

```
// make to lists: one of the date, one of the area
var dates = ee.List(a.aggregate_array('dateFormat'));
var areas = ee.List(a.aggregate_array('area'));
// merge the lists together
print(dates.zip(areas))
```

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c4bce250d295ef664257f731131ddb63)

But probably you want to change your code to something like this: [link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2df1708ee93e8631239c5edee38e3f4e)